# Pricing a kids book on Amazon KDP

Tags: amazon, pricing

I am trying to price an illustrated children's book on Amazon KDP. The MINIMUM price Amazon accepts seems to be $1.99--although I want to make it 0.99. Are there restrictions to doing so for a kids' book?

Answer (score 1):

The price range is determined by the royalty rate and file size, not the subject matter.

Amazon KDP price guidelines vary by:

1. the royalty rate (35% or 70%)
2. the file size of the ebook (if the 35% rate is chosen)

As of April 15, 2016, the [List Price Requirements page](https://kdp.amazon.com/help?topicId=A301WJ6XCJ8KW0) for Amazon Kindle Direct Publishing gave the following minimum and maximum prices for sales in the US:

- The 35% Royalty Option

  - Ebook is less than 3 megabytes: min price $0.99, max price $200.00
  - Greater than or equal to 3 megabytes and less than 10 megabytes: min price $ 1.99, max price $200.00
  - 10 megabytes or greater: min $ 2.99, max $200.00
- The 70% Royalty Option

  - Minimum price $ 2.99, maximum price $9.99
  - There is a Delivery Cost of US $0.15/MB applied to the 70% Royalty Option.

If you are hitting a lower limit of $1.99, what happens when you submit a revised copy of the book that is less than 3 megabytes in size?